# Is there any way to have the body of a page slide over an image at the top of the page like on a WordPress site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code. This is my HTML. I want there to be an image background in the header and the section to slide over the header.

```
<body>
    <header id=slideover>
       <div> Hello World</div>
    </header>
    <section>
        <div> stuff</div>
        <div> stuff</div>
        <div> stuff</div>
    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: You should give more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way you could accomplish that: use a fixed-height header with `position:fixed` and a margin-top of equal to the `header`'s height on the `section`:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  height: 80px;
  background: url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/111091/pexels-photo-111091.jpeg?w=1260&h=750&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb) no-repeat center;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  line-height: 80px;
  padding: 0 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
section {
  margin-top: 80px;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header id=slideover>
       <div> Hello World</div>
    </header>
    <section>
          <div> stuff</div>
          <div> stuff</div>
          <div> stuff</div>
          <div> stuff</div>
          <div> stuff</div>
          <div> stuff</div>
          <div> stuff</div>
          <div> stuff</div>
          <div> stuff</div>
          <div> stuff</div>
          <div> stuff</div>
          <div> stuff</div>
          <div> stuff</div>
          <div> stuff</div>
          <div> stuff</div>
          <div> stuff</div>
          <div> stuff</div>
          <div> stuff</div>
          <div> stuff</div>
          <div> stuff</div>
          <div> stuff</div>
    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: that seems to work, but not on a mobile site. any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have a meta viewport in your `<head>`?  Example: `<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">`

Comment: I do, just not this part: " maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no " , Haven't seen that in anything I've read about viewport metatag.                                 I have this in the head: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">